# Позиционирование DIV точно посередине экрана с полосой прокрутки и без

Tags: html, css

Есть такой код:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;">
<div id="mydiv" style="margin:0 auto;">...</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

содержимое выравнивается по горизонтали по центру, но когда появляется вертикальная полоса прокрутки, div немного сдвигается относительно вертикальной полосы прокрутки. как решить эту особенность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, вам, ссылка:
http://htmlbook.ru/css/position

Думаю поможет.

Comment: тэгу html в CSS добавил overflow-y: scroll и все ок